# How can I generate a C# type class from a JSON object to use this class as an argument in a Minimal API endpoint?

Tags: api, .net-7.0

I have a json object. How I can generate C# type class from this json in runtime.

I tried to generate the type using reflection, but if I have a complex structure in JSON where the element can be a different type, it turns out I need to generate a separate class for each nested type. Generally, the idea is to use JSON as the argument type in the endpoint of the minimal API. After all, I can't use a JSON object as an argument type.

Comment: Please explain your use case better. So you have JSON at application startup time, and during startup you want to generate an endpoint that can accept a _class_ representing that JSON? Or do you want an endpoint that can accept arbitrary JSON? Why do you think you need to generate a class at runtime? You could just read the request body and deserialize that (perhaps into `dynamic`)?

Comment: I get this json at runtime. It comes as a string. I want to use this json as an argument type in RequestDelegateFactory.Create( this generated type from json). I need each endpoint to work only with a certain type, not with any JSON.

Comment: Again, what's your use case? Why do you want to generate endpoints (and their JSON-deserializing model) at runtime? What benefit does binding to a model have, if your code doesn't know about that model until at runtime? You can't like read properties that don't exist at compile-time. Again, if you just want an endpoint that can accept arbitrary JSON, there are different approaches.

Comment: I am dynamically generating endpoints and need the type of the endpoint argument so that I can correctly generate the Open API schema

Comment: I'm sure you can generate OpenAPI metadata differently as well, but if you want to let that be generated from your model declaration, then you should indeed generate all types involved in the JSON, including "nested" (i.e. classes having properties of classes, recursively).

Comment: I have another idea to do this without generating types. Use only the JSON and somehow use it as the type of the endpoint argument. After all, as a result, it turns out to be a JSON argument type.

Comment: But swagger definitions are constructed during webapp startup. With dynamic generation, you should define (manually?) all possible types used in your endpoints. NewstonSoft.Json afaik has JObject class for any json content, but guess it will not help with generation OpenApiDocuments.